# Custom seekbar не применяет цвет background и не меняет размер

Tags: android

Сразу напишу что пост [SeekBar кастомный background, progress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473690/seekbar-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-background-progress) видел, но либо что-то не так делал либо он мне не помог

 Есть задача сделать кастомный seekbar
[image: seekbar]

 с текстом думаю проблем не будет, сделаю сверху наложение.
А вот с самим seekbar  есть проблема. Точнее 2 проблемы.

Проблема №1 При создании он весь зеленый в независимости от положения ползунка.[image: sekbarmy]

Проблема №2 выбор высоты seekbar, несмотря на то что файлы в формате 9-patch
при изменении android:layout_height, seekbar остается одной высоты, меняется только размер фона вокруг. Есть конечно идея использовать android:scaleY, но сколько хорошо такое решение?

```
   <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="25"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_t"
        />
```

seekbar_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:top="14dp" android:bottom="4dp">
        <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/seeksecond"
            android:dither="true"
            />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/seeksecond"
            android:dither="true"
            />
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekfirst"
        />
</layer-list>
```

все графические файлы в формате 9-patch 

seek_t.9.png - черная полоска для ползунка

 seeksecond.9.png - белый квадрат

 seekfirst.9.png  -зеленый квадрат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Искал решение несколько часов, и не мог найти стоило задать вопрос и тут же нашел.

 разметка  без изменения

```
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="25"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
            />
```

seekbar_progress

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#ffffff"
            android:endColor="#ffffff"/>
        <size android:height="@dimen/seekbar_size"/>
    </shape>

</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#33ff00"
                android:endColor="#33ff00"
               />
            <size android:height="@dimen/seekbar_size"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

thumb

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="@dimen/seekbar_size"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Размер высоты можно регулировать через seekbar_size, что позволяет использовать для разных экранов.