# Custom SeekBar не меняется progress

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

Пробую сделать видоизмененный SeekBar и планирую получить, при `max=6` и `progress=3`, примерно такой результат:

[image: планируемый результат SeekBar]

Диагональ экрана в макете выбрана 4,7"WXGA 1280x720px т.к. это соответствует диагонали и разрешению моего телефона на котором я и смотрю результат.

Изначально у меня есть такой фон с уже нарисованным индикатором, назовем его так, в котором есть темные деления (`background.png`):

[image: фон]

Изображение размером 720х1230 px (минус 50 px на статусбар). Поместил на background макета.

На его основе я сделал два фрагмента для индикатора с пустым значением (только серые деления) и выставленными всеми делениями (белыми). Пользователь сам должен выбрать необходимое количество делений. Т.к. индикатор получится вертикальным и SeekBar придется поворачивать на -90 градусов, то изображения я сделал сразу наклоненными. Выглядят пустой и полный индикатор так (`empty.9.png`, `full.9.png`):

[image: empty]
[image: full]

Изображения в формате 9-patch и должны растягиваться от края до края. Изображения поместил в папку `drawable`.

Результат, при `max=6` и `progress=3`, получается таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ползунок посередине, а все деления заполнены белым, хотя должны только до половины, как на самом первом скриншоте вначале. Естественно так быть не должно и это основная проблема вопроса.

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="369px"
        android:layout_height="267px"
        android:layout_marginStart="144.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:max="6"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:progress="3"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
        android:rotation="-90"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

custom_seekbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/empty"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/empty"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/full"/>

</layer-list>
```

Когда не знал про 9-patch, делал все простыми изображениями и результат получался как надо, но не удавалось подогнать SeekBar попиксельно на то место фона, где он должен располагаться. Происходило это потому, что SeekBar с обычными изображениями увеличивался в 2 раза по ширине и высоте(так понимаю связано это с плотностью моего экрана 312 dpi). Соответственно нужно было применять `ScaleX=0.5`, `ScaleY=0.5` и, так же `rotation=-90`. Не знаю на сколько это верное решение, т.к. подобное делаю впервые, но после этого размер seekBar становился чуть больше чем нужно и мне не удавалось достичь нужного результата.

Пробую указать в `custom_seekbar.xml` чтобы атрибут `@android:id/progress` использовал не 9-patch, а обычное изображение, получается частично то, что нужно, но все же не такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Читал похожие вопросы [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473690/seekbar-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-background-progress) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729638/custom-seekbar-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-background-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80), но как-то не очень помогло.

Делаю все это под минимальный API 17 и тестирую все также на устройстве с Android 4.2.2 с DPI 312.

Возможно я вообще не верно все это делаю, тогда очень прошу помочь более опытных, как сделать, что бы SeekBar работал нужным образом и индикатор менял свой вид?

**UPD:** Похоже придется немного пояснить почему я выбрал именно такой вариант создания кастомного SeekBar. В комментариях предлагают отделить индикатор от фона, хотя как это поможет нормальной работе сикбара, я не очень понимаю. Тут несколько неудобств сразу. Сидеть аккуратно по контуру вырезать сикбар, потом чем-то заполнять образовавшееся пустое место, работать со штампом. Все это долго и муторно и, как мне кажется, не стоит того, так как полученное изображение все равно встанет обратно на это самое место. Поэтому и предложил сразу свой вариант решения этого. Какой бы ни был сложности индикатор нарисован на предоставленном изображении, просто .jpg или любой файл содержащий слои, наклонные деления или изогнутые, горизонтальный или вертикальный, его можно перевести в слои просто выделив прямоугольный образец вокруг него. Поясню как это вижу я.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: Отделите фон экрана от заготовки пустого индикатора, и вам не придется больше бороться с 9-patch. Пусть они живут своей жизнью, фон подгоняется под экран, а контрол помещается на нужное место.

Comment: В этом проекте у тебя только данный функционал? Если есть возможность, то отправь исходники мне на почту. Постараюсь что-то сделать. martsinkevych@gmail.com p.s. не совсем понятны ваши аргументы против отделения  seekbar-а от фона

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Нет, отделить не вариант. Все потому что в последующем этот пример будет как прототип для более сложного, где фоном будет приборная панель в виде тоже фона, только уже просто фотографии .jpg, где я не могу что-либо подвинуть, отделить без нарушения целостности картинки и индикаторы на ней нужно анимировать таким же образом. Просто понимаю, что если получится решить проблему с такими условиями, тогда получится выполнить и более сложную задачу. Поэтому для вопроса тут я попробовал максимально упростить и набросал такой пример.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Я может быть слишком однотонный фон добавил в вопросе. Хорошо, если фон будет [таким](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fqch.png), тоже как-то можно их разделить, имея в распоряжении только однослойное изображение? По поводу разделения индикатора от фона, сделал дополнение в конце вопроса. Или я может быть как-то не так это понял, тогда поясните пожалуйста, что конкретно подразумевается под разделением?

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych Да, в этом проекте только данный функционал. Исходники отправил на почту, буду рад, если чем-то сможете помочь. По поводу разделения, сделал дополнение в конце вопроса.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что в вашем случае считать фоном контрола, что фоном экрана. Фон контрола нельзя натягивать на экран, конечно все поползет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось.

custom_seekbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/empty"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/empty"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_clip"/>

</layer-list>
```

Добавился файл progress_clip.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/full"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal">
</clip>
```

Оба изображения для SeekBar 9-patch. Теперь все работает как надо.